# Returning values of a fetch

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

Please look at the code below. It's a Backbone/Parse code that uses some underscore features.
I'm trying to iterate over an Parse class to retrieve "firstName" attributes of all objects in that class.
I have 2 issues with it.
The first one, as indicated with the comment, is that it correctly retrieves the first names, but it duplicates them. So if there are 5 objects, it will retrieve 5 firstName * 5. There is an iteration problem here. This is shown with the console log.

Second problem, is that I try to push firstName values into an array, then return it, so I can use the values later in code using the testt variable. But checking the testt content with a console log sends a message instead of the firstname lists. 
Do you see anyway how to fix this code ?

```
var DoopizCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
        model: Subscribers

    }
);
var doopizlist = new DoopizCollection();
var testt;
testt = doopizlist.fetch({
    success: function(doopizlist) {
       var results = [];
        doopizlist.each(function(object) {
            results.push(doopizlist.pluck('firstName'));
            console.log(doopizlist.pluck('firstName')); // logs 2 duplicate arrays
        });

        return results;
    },
    error: function(doopizlist, error) {
        console.log("error"); // The collection could not be retrieved.
    }
});
console.log(testt);   // logs "a b.promise...." message instead of firstNames
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplication issue is because you are looping over `doopizlist` *twice*, once with `each` and again with `pluck`. Pluck is just basically shorthand of the `map` method.

The second issue is, you are expecting `testt` is the resulting value, when actually it is an instance of [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), which is something known as a *promise*. So you can use the `then` method to log the value of the result.

```
var DoopizCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
        model: Subscribers

    }
);
var doopizlist = new DoopizCollection();
var testt;
testt = doopizlist.fetch({
    success: function(results) {
        return results.pluck('firstName');
    },
    error: function(results, error) {
        console.log("error"); // The collection could not be retrieved.
    }
});

testt.then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know where I can learn more about this promise behavior ?

Comment: Sure, promises are not specific to just Backbone.js. You'll find a lot of javascript libraries (like jQuery) make use of promises. Here's a link I found on Google: http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/ If you don't find that particular helpful try Googling "Javascript Promises" or "Javascript Deferreds".

Comment: Thanks but about the second issue: testt.then logs object Object. Seems it can't really access value returned above. I'm not sure why.

Comment: The `testt.then` should return a new promise so that another `then` can be chained to it. If the promise has been resolved, your result should be passed as the first argument to your callback. If it was rejected you can capture that error by passing a second callback to the `then` method. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) for more details on that.